# Falling Apply the OpenCV on Python For Some ERROR

Tags: python, pip

I'm applying the OpenCV on python ,following the guide provided by the official https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python.
I've updated the `pip` ，and I entered the `pip install opencv-contrib-python` in the command cell .
At first ,the code run smoothly .However, after about 10mins, there was a wrong.

The first part of it, is bellow :

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 435, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 516, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 462, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 506, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket. Timeout: The read operation timed out
```

I also attach the second ERROR part.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 369, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 438, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 483, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 165, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 106, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 573, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 538, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "D:\app\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 440, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Among which ,the "D:\app\Anaconda3" ,is the place my Anaconda located .

I'm wondering how it came plenty of ERROR . Besides, I'm also long for applying the Opencv on my python correctly

It will be appreciate that if someone can solve my confusion and give some advices about applying.

Thank you !

Comment: It means there is a problem with either your internet connection or with the server. It is not a question about programming.

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel ,thank you for your constructive comments .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problems! It's due to my region. It takes more time to download the packages from abroad. I re-download the package successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).